# Calculate Acceleration (Driving a Car)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-motion

I am trying to replicate the acceleration calculation like the application "Dynolicious" but I'm not sure where to head to calculate this. Do I use `Core Motion` or do I do calculations using other numbers?

I have tried using `Core Motion`'s `userAcceleraion` value, but it is not coming out at all like what I'm looking for.

```
coreMotion = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
[coreMotion startDeviceMotionUpdates];

//then every second it updates my label...

NSString *accel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[coreMotion accelerometerData]acceleration].x];
accelerationLabel.text = accel;
```

i.e. I want my values to come out like 0.4, -0.4, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider low pass filtering (shown in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211589/uiacceleration-filtering)), which is actually an Apple guideline (see the [Isolating the Gravity Component from Acceleration Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html) of the Event Handling Programming Guide)

> If you are using the accelerometer data to detect the current
>   orientation of a device, you need to be able to filter out the portion
>   of the acceleration data caused by gravity from the portion of the
>   data that is caused by motion of the device. To do this, you can use a
>   low-pass filter to reduce the influence of sudden changes on the
>   accelerometer data. The resulting filtered values then reflect the
>   more constant effects of gravity.

You can also look at the "Isolating Instantaneous Motion from Acceleration Data" section

> If you are using accelerometer data to detect just the instant motion
>   of a device, you need to be able to isolate sudden changes in movement
>   from the constant effect of gravity. You can do that with a high-pass
>   filter.

It goes on to give a simple implementation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's got some good documentation up about gathering accelleration information at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html

Looks like you need to setup the accelerometer and then use delegate methods to read the data.